# STRUCT | incomplete type error for struct/union

Tags: c, dictionary, struct, linked-list, hashtable

I am currently trying to build a dictionary based on a hash table.
The logic is:
There is a struct called HashTable which contains the following:

```
HashFunc HashFunc;
PrintFunc PrintEntry;
CompareFunc CompareWords;
GetKeyFunc GetEntryKey;
DestroyFunc DestoryEntry;
```

these are pointers to functions (user created to make modular dictionary).

```
_HashArray* HashArray;
int TableSize;
```

HashArray is an array of _HashArray objects -> each is the first element of a linked list.
And TableSize is the size of the HashArray (number of hash values we are able to create).

### Hash.h:

```
typedef enum {FAIL = 0, SUCCESS} Result;
typedef enum {SAME = 0, DIFFERENT} CompResult;

typedef struct _Hash *pHash;

typedef void* pElement;
typedef void* pKey;

typedef int (*HashFunc) (pKey key, int size);
typedef Result (*PrintFunc) (pElement element);
typedef CompResult (*CompareFunc) (pKey key1, pKey key2);
typedef pKey (*GetKeyFunc) (pElement element);
typedef void (*DestroyFunc)(pElement element);
```

### Hash.c

```
typedef struct _List
{
    pElement _Element;
    struct _List* listNext;
} pList;

typedef struct
{
    pList* listFirst;
} _HashArray;

typedef struct
{
    _HashArray* HashArray;
    HashFunc HashFunc;
    PrintFunc PrintEntry;
    CompareFunc CompareWords;
    GetKeyFunc GetEntryKey;
    DestroyFunc DestoryEntry;
    int TableSize;
} _Hash;
```

Deceleration i am trying:

```
pHash HashCreate(int ArraySize, void* HashWord, void* PrintEntry, void* CompareWords, void* GetEntryKey, void* DestroyEntry)
{
        // First set all function pointers
        // Create the hashtable
    pHash newTable = (pHash)malloc(sizeof(_Hash));
    newTable->HashArray = (_HashArray*)malloc(sizeof(_HashArray)*ArraySize);
    newTable->TableSize = ArraySize;
    newTable->HashFunc = HashWord;
    newTable->PrintEntry = PrintEntry;
    newTable->CompareWords = CompareWords;
    newTable->GetEntryKey = GetEntryKey;
    newTable->DestroyEntry = DestroyEntry;
}
```

All newTable-> show errors.

Comment: a pointer to a function is not as written, but rather something similar to void (*function)(param);  The set with something like function = functionName;

Comment: the use of leading underscores in names is a very bad idea.  This is because the compiler pre-pends one or more underscores to names for its' various uses.  This results in problems arising in the symbol table of the object file and problems at link time.  While most modern compilers can handle the problem, it is far better to not create the problem via use of leading underscores in names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your declaration of `pHash` refernces a type `struct _Hash` which does not exist.

Change this:

```
typedef struct
{
    _HashArray* HashArray;
    HashFunc HashFunc;
    PrintFunc PrintEntry;
    CompareFunc CompareWords;
    GetKeyFunc GetEntryKey;
    DestroyFunc DestoryEntry;
    int TableSize;
} _Hash;
```

to this:

```
typedef struct _Hash
{
    _HashArray* HashArray;
    HashFunc HashFunc;
    PrintFunc PrintEntry;
    CompareFunc CompareWords;
    GetKeyFunc GetEntryKey;
    DestroyFunc DestoryEntry;
    int TableSize;
} _Hash;
```

The original declaration creates an anonymous struct, and typedefs it as `_Hash` but nothing creates a `struct _Hash` so the orginal typedef for `pHash` is still incomplete.

Then you have the problem that `_Hash` doesn't have a `DestroyEntry` member (you have a typo in the `struct`.

To make the problem clearer, read this:

```
typedef struct _Hash *pHash;
```

as this:

```
#define pHash struct _Hash *
```

and you will see that your structure definition similarly becomes

```
#define _Hash struct { ... }
```

Which does not name the struct. So there is no such thing as a `struct _Hash` in your program.

With my change it becomes

```
#define _Hash struct _Hash { ... }
```

Answer (score 2):

Every struct definition needs a name. Look at your definition for _List:

```
typedef struct _List {
    pElement _Element;
    struct _List* listNext;
} pList;
```

The above is equivalent to:

```
struct _List {
    pElement _Element;
    struct _List* listNext;
}

typedef struct _List pList;
```

You should always follow either of the above formats for all your struct/typedef definitons. The typdefs for _Hash and _HashArray are referring to unnamed structs.

```
typedef struct HashArray_struct_name_goes_here
{
    pList* listFirst;
} _HashArray;

typedef struct Hash_struct_name_goes_here
{
    _HashArray* HashArray;
    HashFunc HashFunc;
    PrintFunc PrintEntry;
    CompareFunc CompareWords;
    GetKeyFunc GetEntryKey;
    DestroyFunc DestoryEntry;
    int TableSize;
} _Hash;
```

Comment: Actually, there is no requirement in the C standard to name a struct. It simply creates an anonymous struct - which have many uses. An anonymous struct can not easily be copied, passed by value or pointer, or compared. The only way to take the address of one (without casting) is a `void *`.